# In a processing sketch, what is the best way to mark a point with, say four pixels, instead of one

Tags: image-processing, point, pixel

I want to mark points on a Processing sketch display, but `point()` colours just one pixel, which is hardly visible on my monitor screen, so I would like to make it slightly bigger. Please, what is the best way to mark a point with, say four or nine pixels, instead of one? I could use `ellipse()` or `rect()` but these look like a sledgehammer and nut solution. Perhaps loops to draw a 3x3 square round the point maybe best, but I am asking in case there is a well known solution already available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any more authoritative solution, this is what I am using, to draw a 3x3 array of points round the central one:

```html
 void spot(int x, int y) // draws 9 points round the point at x,y
  { for(int i=-1;i<3;i++)
    { for(int j=-1;j<3;j++)
      {point(x+i,y+j);}
    }
  }
```

I will accept this as an answer, when permitted, if no better alternative is suggested.